# Returning bool from ViewModel to View binding

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want a button to change the visibility of a label once i click it.

xaml View:

```
<local:ButtonRenderer Text="Connect" BackgroundColor="#6DCFF6" TextColor="White" Command="{Binding viewTemperature}" CornerRadius="10" WidthRequest="200" IsVisible="{Binding !isConnecting}"/>
<Label Text="PlaceholderText" TextDecorations="Underline" TextColor="White" Margin="0,5,0,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" IsVisible="{Binding !isConnecting}"/>
```

ViewModel

```
viewTemperature = new Command(async () =>
{
    isConnecting = true;
    await _navigation.PushModalAsync(new TemperaturePage());
}) ;

public bool isConnecting
{
    get
    {
        return _isConnecting;
    }
    set
    {
        _isConnecting = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new 
        PropertyChangedEventArgs(_isConnecting.ToString()));
    }
}
```

I have put breakpoints in my code, and the isConnected is being changed to true in my viewmodel. However, the visibility of my label is not changed. I suspect that `PropertyChanged` isn't supposed to change bool values?

Comment: You might need to change it `PropertyChangedEventArgs("isConnecting");`.

Comment: doesn't make any difference unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve your code in `ViewModel`

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
  PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}


private bool isconnecting ;
public bool isConnecting
{
  get
  {
    return isconnecting;
  }

  set
  {
    if (isconnecting != value)
    {
      isconnecting = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Are you able to tell me the difference between using this method, and `PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs()`  ?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do `IsVisible="{Binding !isConnecting}"`, this will not work.

You can either make a InvertBoolConverter, or, the simplier option, use Triggers. Here is a sample:

```
<Label Text="PlaceholderText" TextDecorations="Underline" TextColor="White" Margin="0,5,0,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
            IsVisible="{Binding isConnecting}">
    <Label.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding isConnecting}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
         <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding isConnecting}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
```